# how can i echo item price in php

Tags: php, mysql, barcode

this code create barcode image and echo the item name with barcode
but i want to echo item name with unit price
 how can i do this please help me to fix this issue
thanks

im edit after this code

```
$text = $item['name'];
```

to

### like this

```
$text = $item['name'];

$text2 = $item['unit_price'];
```

but its notworking can anybody tell me whats the problem and how can i fix it

this is my php barcoder script

```
<head>
        <title><?php echo $this->lang->line('items_generate_barcodes'); ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width='50%' align='center' cellpadding='20'>
    <tr>
    <?php 
    $count = 0;
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $barcode = $item['id'];

        $text = $item['name'];

        if ($count % 2 ==0 and $count!=0)
        {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
        echo "<td><img src='".site_url()."/barcode?barcode=$barcode&text=$text&$text&width=256' /></td>";
        $count++;
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is mysql structure

```
name            varchar(255)     latin1_swedish_ci          No                                   
category    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No                                   
supplier_id int(11)         Yes NULL                                
item_number varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       Yes NULL                                 
description varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No                                   
cost_price  double(15,2)            No                                  
unit_price  double(15,2)            No                                  
quantity    double(15,2)            No  0.00                                
reorder_level   double(15,2)            No  0.00                                
location    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No                                   
item_id int(10)         No      auto_increment                          
allow_alt_description   tinyint(1)          No                                  
is_serialized   tinyint(1)          No                                  
deleted int(1)          No  0                               
expire
```

here is my mysql barcode function

```
function generate_barcodes($item_ids)
{
    $result = array();

    $item_ids = explode(':', $item_ids);
    foreach ($item_ids as $item_id)
    {
        $item_info = $this->Item->get_info($item_id);

        $result[] = array('name' =>$item_info->name, 'id'=> $item_id);
    }

    $data['items'] = $result;
    $this->load->view("barcode_sheet", $data);
}
```

Comment: You have to make sure you have the data `item_price` available through the query your reading data from

Comment: yes i have a data in item_price

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have `unit_price` available in your `$item` array from the database.

In your `foreach` loop, replace this line `$text = $item['name'];` with this:

```
$text = $item['name'] . ' $' . number_format($item['unit_price'], 2);
```

This is how the code should look:

```
<head>
        <title><?php echo $this->lang->line('items_generate_barcodes'); ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width='50%' align='center' cellpadding='20'>
    <tr>
    <?php 
    $count = 0;
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $barcode = $item['id'];

        $text = $item['name'] . ' $' . number_format($item['unit_price'], 2);

        if ($count % 2 ==0 and $count!=0)
        {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
        echo "<td><img src='".site_url()."/barcode?barcode=$barcode&text=$text&$text&width=256' /></td>";
        $count++;
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: dear i update and check it then showing error Disallowed Key Characters and image is also not showing of barcode

Comment: url showing like this index.php/barcode?barcode=1&text=Laptop%20$0.00&Laptop%20$0.00&width=256 and unitprice is not came in url see %20$0.00&

Answer (score 0):

I have the strong feeling that your SELECT statement lacks the unit_price column.
Please show us your SELECT statement that poppulates your $items array.

Comment: function generate_barcodes($item_ids)
 {
  $result = array();

  $item_ids = explode(':', $item_ids);
  foreach ($item_ids as $item_id)
  {
   $item_info = $this->Item->get_info($item_id);

   $result[] = array('name' =>$item_info->name, 'id'=> $item_id);
  }

  $data['items'] = $result;
  $this->load->view("barcode_sheet", $data);
 }
 here is my select statement i think how can i edit a unit_price in that